# Merge objects to one array after find

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6, antd

I have a function wherein I find specific date with array of dates in a calendar. But I still need it to be inside an array. How can I merge them? Here's the scenario

This is the data I get after submitting a form. This is after consoling `employeeLeaves` in my code below.

[image]

```
const getEmployeeLeave = value => {
let employeeLeaves = [...isEmployeeLeave];

const calendarDates = value.toString();
const formatCalendarDates = moment(calendarDates).format('YYYY-MM-DD');

console.log(employeeLeaves);

return (
  employeeLeaves.find(item => item.startDate == formatCalendarDates) || []
);
```

};

After that code is executed, I get the return from another function

```
 const dateCellRender = value => {
   let employeeListLeave = getEmployeeLeave(value);
 };
```

I got 2 objects returned but not in array. How can I merge them into one array so I can map them and render it like listing inside the calendar.
[image]

It should be like this in the mockup
[image]

Answer (score 0):

`Array.prototype.find` will return the first item in the array that matches your test. If you need to find multiple matches, you should rather use `Array.prototype.filter`. That will return an array of all item that matches your test. [cf. here for more details on the filter method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)

Comment: Hello. I tried the filter but I still get separate objects. Not sure what's wrong with my code. But I tried separately using filter and works fine.